# Man is recruited to talk to a captured alien

Tags: identify-this-movie

I need a real movie-buff on this one. I'm looking for movie which concerns a man who is recruited to try and talk to a captured alien. Now this is where things are getting a little hazy so I'll just list the things I remember clearly:

1. The protagonist was abducted and he was sought out for this reason.
2. The alien refuses to talk for many sessions.
3. The alien was of the small grey type that are very popular today.
4. The alien was dressed in a silvery suit with some type of decals, possibly red in color.
5. The protagonist dresses up like the alien in a desperate attempt to jumpstart communications.
6. The alien finally speaks to the protagonist but does so telepathically.
7. The protagonist does not disclose this information to his handlers.
8. He elects to free the alien instead.
9. The alien has powers to obscure the minds of men and can put a different face and even voice to the protagonist.
10. The alien is slowly dying.
11. The alien thinks trees are beautiful.
12. The alien believes he will dream of trees when he dies.
13. There was a female love-interest that they picked up along the way, possibly a carjacking.
14. The woman quickly realizes the stakes and begins to help the fugitives.
15. I don't remember the ending but I do remember them getting very close to the alien spacecraft.

Can anyone help me with a title here? It might be a TV-movie. I've tried my damndest to find it myself - I've even gone through entire lists of movies featuring aliens on Wikipedia but with no luck which I why I think it might be a TV-movie.

Thanks and a happy new years to all.

19/1-15: Post edited for clarity. Information added. Spelling check. Errors removed.

Comment: Was this a made for TV movie? Also, when did you see it and from what apparent time period (production wise)?

Comment: I think it was made for TV yes, but I base this belief purely on my inability to find this movie on any lists or websites. I originally searched for this movie in conjuction with close encounters of the third kind, but only because they are so similar. I am faily sure this movie is at least ten years younger than close encounters.

Comment: This is great information in addition to your question. When asking questions in the future like this, it is highly advisable your include such information and be as complete as possible. It will help tremendously in your efforts to get the answer you desire ;-)

Comment: What did the alien look like? Human-like? or anything distinguishing? Bug-eyes, antenna, etc?

Comment: Language\country? B&W or color? And is it possible it was a TV episode?

Comment: Language was English and I'm leaning towards American TV-movie or possibly a mini-series shown in full. It was in color and I don't think it was an episode of anything because I can remember pretty good production values and  effects such as morphing - The alien was pretty convincing and I'm still not sure if it was a puppet or little person in a suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Official Denial](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110715/combined) from 1994:

> A man who claims to have been abducted by aliens is also abducted by a top secret government agency, the Majestic Group, who want him to attempt to communicate with the only surviving alien from a UFO shot down by the Air Force. Telepathically, the alien tells him it must be returned to its ship, where it will reveal a secret vital to the future of the planet.

You've described the movie well: all the details are there. The alien (who's a classic grey in a silver suit) says he'll dream of trees before he dies. The protagonist dresses like the alien and also shaves his head to communicate with him. Here's a clip from the film, where you can see one of the sessions around 0:55:

Comment: And here's my [previous suggestion](http://www.vardulon.com/2011/04/tales-from-darkside-201-placeholder.html), before the re-edit. Though wrong, the plot is surprisingly similar.

Comment: You did it! :D Thank you very much. Expertly done. How did you find it??

Comment: Associations, mostly, and used Youtube to verify (it's there in its entirety). I don't think I've seen this film before. Glad you found it. :)

Comment: I don't know how much of your private time you used but thank you for every minute - You sir, are a scholar and gentleman.

Comment: Face!!!!!!!!!!!!